# Adding a new folder/file to already existing android project?

Tags: android

I wanted to add a sound clip to my already existing android project. I am not able to add a new folder to the project, because when I clean up the project it deletes the R.java file. The same thing happens when i add the files directly.

I created my folder in the start\res\ but it wont work.

Comment: couldn't get you.... elaborate and leave your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add your music file in raw folder inside the res folder...

```
res/raw/mymusic.mp3
```

Comment: can we add another folder that is not named "raw"?

Comment: We can use only pre defined folder given in api      [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add you soundclip file in **assets** folder and rebuild your project.

[image]

Comment: You can create folder inside assets folder